# How to bind a Combobox to an ObservableCollection with SelectedItem dependant on ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, listbox

I have a combobox, which draws it's items from an ObservableCollection of a custom type using Bindings. I've set the DisplayMemberPath so it displays the correct string and stuff. Now I'm fiddling with the SelectedItem/SelectedValue. It needs to be dependant on the selected item of a ListBox, which is bound to a different ObservableCollection of another custom type, but which has a property of the same type of the ComboBox list.

How can I bind this using MVVM? Is it even possible?

I've got my code here:

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private ObservableCollection<Plugin<IPlugin>> erpPlugins;
    public ObservableCollection<Plugin<IPlugin>> ERPPlugins
    {
        get
        {
            return erpPlugins;
        }
        set
        {
            erpPlugins = value;
            OnProprtyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Plugin<IPlugin>> shopPlugins;
    public ObservableCollection<Plugin<IPlugin>> ShopPlugins
    {
        get
        {
            return shopPlugins;
        }
        set
        {
            shopPlugins = value;
            OnProprtyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Connection> connections;
    public ObservableCollection<Connection> Connections
    {
        get {
            return connections;
        }
        set
        {
            connections = value;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        instance = this;

        ERPPlugins = new ObservableCollection<Plugin<IPlugin>>(GenericPluginLoader<IPlugin>.LoadPlugins("plugins").Where(x => x.PluginInstance.Info.Type == PluginType.ERP));
        ShopPlugins = new ObservableCollection<Plugin<IPlugin>>(GenericPluginLoader<IPlugin>.LoadPlugins("plugins").Where(x => x.PluginInstance.Info.Type == PluginType.SHOP));
        Connections = new ObservableCollection<Connection>
        {
            new Connection("test") { ERP = ERPPlugins[0].PluginInstance, Shop = ShopPlugins[0].PluginInstance } // Debug
        };
    }
```

Connection.cs

```
public class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionName { get; set; }
    public IPlugin ERP { get; set; }
    public IPlugin Shop { get; set; }

    public Connection(string connName)
    {
        ConnectionName = connName;
    }
}
```

And the XAML snippet of my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox 
    Margin="10,77,232,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    x:Name="cmbERP" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ERPPlugins}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=lbVerbindungen, Path=SelectedItem.ERP}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="PluginInstance.Info.Name"
    >
```

Comment: `SelectedItem.ERP` needs to be something that the CLR will consider equal to an item in `ERPPlugins` (or to a property of one, if you go with `SelectedValue`). It can be a value type or a String, or a reference type that's actually in the `ItemsSource` collection, or you can override `Equals`. If `IPlugin` has any kind of unique ID property that's a value type (`int`, `Guid`, etc.) or `String`, I'd prefer using `SelectedValue`/`SelectedValuePath` with that. Overriding Equals on a reference type can bite you elsewhere in your code. But it's there as a last resort.

Comment: IIRC bindings will use IEquatable, if implemented, to make the comparison between instances.

Comment: @Will I just tested that. Something is calling `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)`, but the selected item gets selected only if I override `Equals(Object)`, and I don't need `IEquatable` for that to work.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that's a shame.  WPF is usually pretty good about things like this (e.g., using TypeDescriptors to access property values when properly attributed).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Aight, so I'd just set the Id field on loading the plugins

Comment: Just a quick question, how would I do the SelectValue for it? The Lists are all type Plugin<IPlugin>, not IPlugin, since I need some more information, which are added by the program itself (like types, assembly and the instance)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved it by changing the IPlugin type in the Connection to Plugin. Why I used IPlugin there in the first place is beyond my knowledge. But like this, I have the same type of Plugin everywhere.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it